# Flattern data by count

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have some data like this:

```
# of jobs  count
---------  -----
1          2
2          3
3          1
4          1
```

They represent a [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) {1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4}. I want to do statistics (medium, mean, mode) against the multiset. Is there any way to somehow generate this list from the 4x2 data above? That way I can use the built-in functions ([`MEDIUM`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/median-function-d0916313-4753-414c-8537-ce85bdd967d2)/[`AVERAGE`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/average-function-047bac88-d466-426c-a32b-8f33eb960cf6)/[`MODE`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mode-function-e45192ce-9122-4980-82ed-4bdc34973120)). Currently I’m using [`SUMPRODUCT`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumproduct-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e) to calculate mean, and a combination of [`MAX`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/max-function-e0012414-9ac8-4b34-9a47-73e662c08098)/[`MATCH`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a)/[`INDEX`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) to get the mode, but I can’t figure out a way to calculate medium.

Note:

1. Of course the real data is much more than 4 rows, but the idea should be the same.
2. The first column is sorted integers, if that helps.
3. It’s OK to use some auxiliary cells to hold intermediate data.
4. It doesn’t have to be a formula; if pivot table is a better tool, please advise.

Comment: You can find some answers on getting median specifically if you search on Excel median from frequency data

Comment: This can be done in `Power Query`, available in Excel 2010+, if you like

Comment: @TomSharpe Thank you very much. Turns out that I didn’t know the term “frequency data” and this is exactly what I need; searching for “median from frequency data” gives me tons of useful information.

Answer (score 2):

With access to `CONCAT` you could use:

```
=FILTERXML(CONCAT("<t><s>",REPT(A2:A5&"</s><s>",B2:B5),"</s></t>"),"//s[node()]")
```

This would return `{1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4}` and you could directly apply the other functions, e.g.:

```
=MEDIAN(FILTERXML.....) etc.
```